# Windows Server 2012 R2 OS and oracle 12 C cluster configuration

Tags: oracle12c, failover, windows-clustering

I want know how to build oracle 12c Cluster on windows server 2012 R2.(for two node cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Install oracle and failsafe on local drive...more details please contact shiv.waychal@gmail.com